# ORACE How to get begin of the day from CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem with solving this problem. I have to extract the IDs of data from a table that has been changed only today. My current solution is

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM changes_table
WHERE valid_to > (SELECT TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE, 'DD-MON-RR') FROM DUAL)
```

This works in BDeaver but not in my application, there I get "ORA-01843:"

So is it possible to use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, but it take timestamp from now. Is it possible to change it to format DD-MON-RR with 00:00:00 time?

Or is there any other solution?

I can send only one SQL command.

Comment: Column valid_to data type?

Comment: It's in TIMESTAMP format/data type

Comment: **Never** call `TO_DATE()` on a value which is already a `DATE`, use `TRUNC()`

Answer (score 2):

You may simply use `SYSDATE` here truncated to midnight:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM changes_table
WHERE valid_to > TRUNC(SYSDATE);  -- RHS is today at midnight
```

Note that the above should work whether `valid_to` be a date or a timestamp.